# .htaccess - DirectoryIndex for one folder

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, directoryindex

I have a symfony backend installed on my server and in the symfony/web folder I have created a new folder "app" and there is an index.html. If I call https://example.com/app/ I'm getting 404 and with https://example.com/app/index.html it is working. I have tried to change the DirectoryIndex in the symfony .htaccess from this:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
```

To this:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php index.html
```

But it is still not working. How can I do it that if I call example.com/app/ the index.html will be opened (just for that folder to not destroy the symfony settings)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line at top of your `app/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# remaining rules go below this
```

Comment: Yes thats working. But it appends also /index.html behind the url. It would be nice if it remains /app/

Comment: check my updated answer. Keep redirect rule at the top and all your rules below my commanded line. Then test from a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it:

```
# end of routing.yml
redirect_to_index:
    path: /app/?
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /app/index.html
        permanent: true
```

But it will be `/app/index.html`, not just `/app/`.

Comment: Would be nice if it remains just /app/ if you call it, without index.html behind it. And with your solution if I call example.com/app (without last slash) I'm getting 404 again.

Comment: If you only want `/app/`, yes you need to update the `.htaccess`